# How to accept str.chars() or str.bytes() in a function and iterate twice?

Tags: string, rust, iteration, traits

Is there any way to pass `somestring.chars()` or `somestring.bytes()` to a function and allow that function to reconstruct the iterator?

An example is below. The goal is for the function to be able to iterate through `coll` multiple times, reconstructing it as needed using `into_iter()`. It works correctly for vectors and arrays, but I have not been able to get it working for the string iterator methods.

```rs
// Lifetime needed to indicate the iterator objects
// don't disappear
fn test_single<'a, I, T>(collection: &'a I)
where
    &'a I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    T: Display,
{
    let count = collection.into_iter().count();
    println!("Len: {}", count);

    for x in collection.into_iter() {
        println!("Item: {}", x);
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Works
    test_single(&[1, 2, 3, 4]);
    test_single(&vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);

    let s = "abcd";

    // Desired usage; does not work
    // test_single(&s.chars());
    // test_single(&s.bytes());
}
```

The general error is that `Iterator` is not implemented for `&Chars<'_>`. This doesn't make sense because [chars definitely does implement `IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#impl-IntoIterator) and [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#impl-Iterator)

Is there a solution that allows for the desired usage of `test_single(&s.chars())`?

Link to the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=230ee86cd109384a1c62c362aed9d47f

(`IntoIterator` is prefered over `Iterator` for my application, since I also need to specify that `IntoIterator::IntoIter` is a `DoubleEndedIterator`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can work but not the way you have it written.

You can't iterate a shared reference because `Iterator::next()` takes `&mut self`.  `IntoIterator::into_iter()` *could* be made to work with e.g. `&Chars`, but that's not necessary because `Chars` and `Bytes` both implement `Clone`, which creates a copy of the iterator (but doesn't duplicate the underlying data).

So you just need to adjust your bounds and accept the iterator by value, cloning it when you will need another iterator later:

```
fn test_single<I, T>(collection: I)
where
    I: Clone + IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    T: Display,
{
    let count = collection.clone().into_iter().count();
    println!("Len: {}", count);

    for x in collection.into_iter() {
        println!("Item {}", x);
    }
}
```

Now you can call `test_single(s.chars())`, for example.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a80024ab905238301d6533b4c93e7424))

---

Side note: You can express the type `I` purely with `impl`, which might be more readable:

```
fn test_single(collection: impl Clone + IntoIterator<Item=impl Display>) {
```

Comment: Awesome! That’s perfect, thank you. For a sanity check - since an array/slice/vector still has to be passed as a &reference, `clone` only copies that reference correct? And not every value of the data structure.

Comment: @TrevorGross Well, you technically could use this with a raw vector for example, which would clone the whole vector. To avoid that, instead pass `v.iter()` for example.

Comment: That's very interesting. I _think_ I might have come up with a way to clone the produced `Iterator` (in my case `DoubleEndedIterator`) instead of the `IntoIterator` which I think should at least prevent multiple clones of the underlying when I need the iterator multiple times and the user passes the object instead of a reference. [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e61d8bc6b13583eabab72d35e76a9a2e). Thank you for the advice

Comment: @TrevorGross Yep, that's another valid way to do it.